# How to automatically connect to Broadband Modem

Tags: windows-vista, internet, connection, broadband

Is there a way I can automatically connect to any Broadband modem so I can access the internet on Windows Vista, without first setting up the connection and typing in the IP address and the password?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to switch frequently between various connections, have a look at this:

> **[NetSetMan](http://www.netsetman.com/index.php?s=nsm)** allows you to quickly switch between pre-configured
>   network settings. The program is ideal
>   for people on the road, who frequently
>   connect to different networks and need
>   to update or reconfigure their network
>   settings each time. NetSetMan
>   eliminates the need for manual
>   configurations, you can simply create
>   different profiles to store your
>   network configuration, and then switch
>   between them with the click of a
>   button. NetSetMan can apply
>   configuration settings for IP address
>   Subnet Mask, Default Gateway, WiFi,
>   Printer, DNS servers and more. The
>   free version is limited to 6 network
>   profiles, which is more than enough
>   for personal usage - commercial usage
>   requires a license.

[image]

or this:

**[IP Organizer 2](http://www.bilgisayar-dunyasi.com/yazilim/iporganizer.html)** does what it says on the tin, and it does it for free. pretty much like NetSetMan, it allows you to switch between multiple network profiles (unlimited). NetSetMan features more functions but is only free for private use while IP Organizer 2 is free as in free beer.

[image]

The website is in Turkish, here's the [download link](http://www.bilgisayar-dunyasi.com/yazilim/dosyalar/IP_Organizer2.exe).

Comment: "Bilgisayar Dünyası" means "Computer World" in Turkish ;)

Comment: .... sağ olun :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a router available, you can set it up to manage the connection for you. It will then be able to automatically provide you a DHCP lease when your computer starts up -- no fiddling with usernames and passwords.

If you want to use various networks, [Net Profiles](http://code.google.com/p/netprofiles/) can make connecting to each one a breeze:

[image]

Net Profiles is free and open source.